# Need Regex pattern for this Date

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation, python-datetime

I have date string like

```
  Date: April 1st, 2015
  Date: March 31st, 2015
  Date: March 26th, 2015
```

I need to extract this date which is suitable to python datetime pattern.
I will do `'%B %d %Y'` as python datetime pattern.

So how can i extract above string to datetime format.
Regex output should be:

```
March 31 2015
August 1 2014
```

Please help me to build nice regex pattern.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/eX8bR6/1 something like this - you can use capturing groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How i would do it:

```
date = 'Date: April 1st, 2015'
import re
regex = re.search(
    r'Date:\s([A-Z]{1}[a-z]*)\s([0-9]{1,2})[a-z]{2},\s([0-9]{4})',
    date,
)
parsed_date = ' '.join(regex.groups())
from datetime import datetime
date_time = datetime.strptime(parsed_date, '%B %d %Y')

print date_time
#output
'2015-04-01 00:00:00'
```

now just put this in a lood and do something with the dates ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
^.*?:\s*|[a-zA-Z]+,
```

You can use `re.sub` for this and replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/42#python

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^.*?:\s*|[a-zA-Z]+,', re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = " Date: April 1st, 2015\n Date: March 31st, 2015\n Date: March 26th, 2015"
subst = ""

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Date:\s*(\w+)\s*(\d+)\w+,\s*(\d+)
```

This will put each element of the date in the succeeding captured parameters (1, 2, 3), available through the x.group(n) syntax.

```
>>> ' '.join(re.match(r'Date:\s*(\w+)\s*(\d+)\w+,\s*(\d+)', 'Date: April 1st, 2015').groups())
'April 1 2015'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime.datetime.strptime` and `strftime` :

```
>>> d=datetime.datetime.strptime('April 1 2015','%B %d %Y')
datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 0, 0)

>>> d.strftime('%B %d %Y')
'April 01 2015'
```